# What is the correct way of writing an exclusive left-join on two tables?

Tags: sql, left-join

Do I need to write condition 'is NULL' for two (or could be more) keys when doing an exclusive left join of two tables? The question is if the 'WHERE B.columnName1 IS NULL' is enough?

Join with one key condition:

```
SELECT columns
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON A.columnName = B.columnName
WHERE B.columnName IS NULL
```

Is the following more accurate?   Do I need condition for columnName2?

```
SELECT columns
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON A.columnName1 = B.columnName1
AND  A.columnName2 = B.columnName2
WHERE B.columnName1 IS NULL 
AND B.columnName2 IS NULL
```

So far it worked with one condition but I just got confused, I see this is simple question, sorry for that

Comment: By "exclusive left-join"... do you mean an anti-join?

Comment: Yes, didn't know what is the most common naming for it

Comment: "exclusive left join of two tables" doesn't mean anything. Don't make up a name, say what you mean. PS Clarify via edits, not comments. PS [mre] please.

Answer (score 2):

Single column is enough(as long as it is not nullable):

```
SELECT columns
FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B
  ON A.columnName = B.columnName
WHERE B.columnName IS NULL;
```

Best practice is to use primary key for tableB

Comment: Thanks, but for sure I join by two columns, like this: SELECT columns
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON A.columnName1 = B.columnName1
AND  A.columnName2 = B.columnName2
WHERE B.columnName1 IS NULL

Comment: @Nata Yes, if you have compound FK relationship based on two-columns PK, then single column is enough

Comment: @Nata: you shouldn't be joining on multiple columns "just to be sure". You should join on all columns that make up the foreign key between tableb and tablea

Answer (score 0):

The `ON` clause contains the condition for the join:

```
ON A.columnName = B.columnName
```

If this condition is not met then the result is that all columns of the unmatched row of table `B` will be `NULL`, so your 2nd query is not wrong.
**But**, this also means that `B.columnName` itself is `NULL` and this condition only in the `WHERE` clause is enough.
 
It simply means that in this row `A.columnName` has no matching `B.columnName`.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use a column that is part of the `ON` clause, which your code is doing:

```
SELECT columns
FROM TableA A LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     TableB B
     ON A.columnName = B.columnName
WHERE B.columnName IS NULL;
```

The `JOIN` does not treat `NULL` values as equal.  Equally, the primary key (or any component of the primary key) also works fine.

If you don't want to think about this, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT columns
FROM TableA A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TableB B
                  WHERE A.columnName = B.columnName
                 );
```